# US Visa for spouse

Tags: visas, usa, egyptian-citizens

I am an American citizen living in Egypt. I am pregnant and I would like to give birth to my baby in USA.

Can my husband accompany me to the US and if so which visa does he require?

Comment: What is the citizenship of your husband? Are you settled in Egypt, and intending to return there after the birth?

Comment: In short Husband would just get a normal tourist visa.  If Husband then wants to move permanently to the USA, he will need an immigration attorney once he is in the USA.  They are trivial to find in the phone book.

Comment: Welcome new user, could be this question is more for the "expats" site?

Comment: My husband is an Egyptian citizen , i am intending to return to Egypt after birth

Answer (score 2):

Your husband would apply for a standard B2 or B1/B2 visa to visit the USA.

Note that there may be a strong presumption of immigration intent due to you being an American citizen. He can help reduce this by showing that he has strong ties to Egypt (work; a home; family ties).

How the immigration officer views your husband’s immigration intent will be tied to your plans. You shouldn’t try to hide or deceive the officer as that’ll really raise their suspicions. If you can show that you’re returning to Egypt as well and that you are going back to work or have daycare lined up in Egypt, that’ll show you have no intent to stay in the USA and that he also has no intent to permanently stay in the USA. You might also want to show you have enough money or insurance to cover a birth in the USA (which can range from $10,000 upwards).

Comment: I think you mean B-2 or B-1/B-2 visa.  B-1 is for business visits.